# How show Empty string in Textbox when Date is NULL

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a DateTime as this is C#:

```
public DateTime ShipmentDate { get; set; }
```

I show the value in textbox

This is in cshml:

```
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="ShipmentDate">Shipment Date:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="ShipmentDate" id="ShipmentDate" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
```

And this is in JavaScript:

```
   $('#ShipmentDate').val($.formatDate(PurchaseOrder.ShipmentDate));
```

When ShipmentDate is nullable like this:

```
 public DateTime? ShipmentDate { get; set; }
```

and the date is empty, it shows some random Date as 1960/12/31 in textbox

When ShipmentDate is not nullable shows the date as: 1/1/0001 in textbox

In both in C# date is Null and when I do console.log shows null in the console.
How I can show empty String in textbox when ShipmentDate in Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `PurchaseOrder.ShipmentDate` can be null, it is worth handling this case so that the `$.formatDate(null)` doesn't return an invalid date as noticed.

In Javascript, if a variable is `null` then is treated as a falsy value. So it only executes the `formatDate` if the `ship` is not one of the many [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), including `null`.

```
const ship = PurchaseOrder.ShipmentDate;
$('#ShipmentDate').val(ship ? $.formatDate(ship) : "");
```

Comment: @testind_22 - How to not return null?

Comment: It depends on how it is sent to the browser. If you have control over the server, make sure that you'll only send a not null to the client.